# Send Raw List of JSON in System.Net.Http in UWP C#

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

How to send a **list** of Json without converting into JsonString in C# .NET. I'm using C# 10 with .NET5. I'm using `System.Net.Http` for sending post requests. Anyone please help me with this...

Comment: Any examples about the used concrete input and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send it as a plain `System.String` (`string`) using `System.Net.Http.StringContent`:

```
var json = "...";
var data = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var url = "https://httpbin.org/post";
using var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://url.com", data);
```

Comment: Gotcha, Thank you mate..,